# Intercambiar filas por columnas con valores duplicados

Tags: base-de-datos, r, estructuras-de-datos

estoy trabajando con los siguientes datos:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1811,1811,1522,7121),
                   pregunta=c("17", "17", "20", "21"),
                   valor=c("13","2","12","15"))

    id pregunta valor
1811       17    13
1811       17     2
1522       20    12
7121       21    15
```

Y quisiera hacer una transformación para obtener:

```
     id p17.1 p17.2 p20 p21
1: 1811    13     2  NA  NA
2: 1522    NA    NA  12  NA
3: 7121    NA    NA  NA  21
```

También, si el  ejemplo fuera este:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1811, 1811, 1522,1366, 7121),
                   pregunta = c("17", "17","20","21", "21"),
                   valor = c("13", "2", "12","21", "15"))
```

La solución deseada sería:

```
id p17.1 p17.2 p20 p21
1811    13     2  NA  NA
1522    NA    NA  12  NA
1366    NA    NA  NA  21
7121    NA    NA  NA  15
```

Utilizo:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
     gather(valor, -`id`, -pregunta) %>% 
     spread(pregunta, valor)
```

Pero al tener valores duplicados obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2)
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped
```

Me interesa crear tantas variables como valores tiene la variable Pregunta, el problema es que al repetirse valores de Pregunta, da ese error.

He probado de otras maneras pero al final siempre llego al problema de los valores duplicados.

Answer (score 2):

Es relativamente fácil si primero creas un identificador dentro de cada gruopo "pregunta", como se puede hacer esto? A través de una combinacion de `group_by`, `mutate` y las funciones auxiliares `row_number` y `unite`. Luego de esto creas un identificador único lo que puedes usar con spread.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(id = c(1811, 1811, 1522, 7121), pregunta = c("17", "17", 
  "20", "21"), valor = c("13", "2", "12", "15"))

data_con_id <- data %>%
  group_by(pregunta) %>%
  mutate(fila = row_number()) %>% 
  unite("preg.fila", pregunta, fila)
data_con_id
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id preg.fila valor
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <fct>
#> 1 1811. 17_1      13   
#> 2 1811. 17_2      2    
#> 3 1522. 20_1      12   
#> 4 7121. 21_1      15

data_con_id %>%
  spread(preg.fila, valor)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id `17_1` `17_2` `20_1` `21_1`
#>   <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
#> 1 1522. <NA>   <NA>   12     <NA>  
#> 2 1811. 13     2      <NA>   <NA>  
#> 3 7121. <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   15
```

## Actualización.

En caso que no quieras los `_1` podrías usar la función auxiliar `n()` la cual cuenta la cantidad elementos en el grupo. Luego de esos, puedes **condicionar** con `ifelse` el formato del nombre de la comluna en caso de que la cantidad de elementos por la pregunta sea 1 o no.

```r
data_con_id <- data %>%
  group_by(pregunta) %>%
  mutate(
    fila = row_number(),
    cantidad_de_filas = n()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
data_con_id
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>      id pregunta valor  fila cantidad_de_filas
#>   <dbl> <fct>    <fct> <int>             <int>
#> 1 1811. 17       13        1                 2
#> 2 1811. 17       2         2                 2
#> 3 1522. 20       12        1                 1
#> 4 7121. 21       15        1                 1


data_con_id <- data_con_id %>%
  mutate(preg_fila = ifelse(
    cantidad_de_filas == 1,
    as.character(pregunta),
    paste(pregunta, fila, sep = "_")
    )
  )
data_con_id
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>      id pregunta valor  fila cantidad_de_filas preg_fila
#>   <dbl> <fct>    <fct> <int>             <int> <chr>    
#> 1 1811. 17       13        1                 2 17_1     
#> 2 1811. 17       2         2                 2 17_2     
#> 3 1522. 20       12        1                 1 20       
#> 4 7121. 21       15        1                 1 21

data_con_id %>%
  select(id, valor, preg_fila) %>%
  spread(preg_fila, valor)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id `17_1` `17_2` `20`  `21` 
#>   <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct> <fct>
#> 1 1522. <NA>   <NA>   12    <NA> 
#> 2 1811. 13     2      <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3 7121. <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  15
```

Comment: Efectivamente así funciona, ahora se me ha presentado otro "problema", si el Id es el mismo la solución que me das es buena, pero si ID es distina pero la pregunta es el mismo número, no quiero que me cree una nueva columna, sino que en la misma pregunta ponga el valor uno debajo del otro.

data <- data.frame(id = c(1811, 1811, 1522,1366, 7121),
                   pregunta = c("17", "17","20","21", "21"),
                   valor = c("13", "2", "12","21", "15"))
id p17.1 p17.2 p20 p21
1811    13     2  NA  NA
1522    NA    NA  12  NA
1366    NA    NA  NA  21
7121    NA    NA  NA  15

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Me ha surgido otra duda, más abajo la planteo.

Comment: Ok, debieses eliminar la pregunta, que pusiste en la sección de respuestas. Es mejor uso de esta plataforma si actualizas tu pregunta en crear de una respuesta que es una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Realizada la actualizaciòn!

Answer (score 2):

Sin duda la respuesta de @jbkunst es la indicada, pero como no has mencionado que específicamente la solución sea por medio de `dplyr` me atrevo a darte una alternativa con la funcionalidad base de **R**:

#### Usando [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html):

```
data$no <- paste0(data$pregunta, ".", ave(data$id, paste(data$id,data$pregunta), FUN = seq_along))
new.data <- reshape(data[,-2], direction = "wide", idvar=c("id"), timevar = "no")
names(new.data) = gsub("valor.", "p", names(new.data))
new.data

    id p17.1 p17.2 p20.1 p21.1
1 1811    13     2  <NA>  <NA>
3 1522  <NA>  <NA>    12  <NA>
4 7121  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    15
```

O bien con este ejemplo:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1811, 1811, 1522,1366, 7121), 
                   pregunta = c("17", "17","20","21", "21"), 
                   valor = c("13", "2", "12","21", "15"))
```

Obtendríamos:

```
    id p17.1 p17.2 p20.1 p21.1
1 1811    13     2  <NA>  <NA>
3 1522  <NA>  <NA>    12  <NA>
4 1366  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    21
5 7121  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    15
```

Con: `paste0(data$pregunta, ".", ave(data$id, paste(data$id,data$pregunta), FUN = seq_along))` generamos una nueva columna que representa un id único por id/pregunta/valor, numerando cada elemento del grupo, así para la pregunta 17 tendremos una `17_1` y otra `17_2`. Luego simplemente con `reshape()` transformamos los datos a un formato ancho. Y por último simplemente normalizamos los nombres de las columnas a algo más similar a lo que estabas buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Como bien dices, no indique que usar. 
Como le digo a @jbkunst me ha surgido otra duda, por si quieres echarle un vistazo.

Comment: @Uko, es lógico tu comentario, se me paso por el alto el caso. Ahí hice un pequeño ajuste para contemplar la situación que mencionas. De cualquier manera espera la respuesta de jkbunst, sigo pensando que  `dplyr` sobre todo si ya lo estás usando es una mejor solución. Saludos